# phoenix: post a model with has_many keep throw preloading error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I will show some related code here, but if you need complete code, you can find it on Github: https://github.com/maple-leaf/phoenix_todo

user_model:

```
defmodule PhoenixTodo.User do
  use PhoenixTodo.Web, :model

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :email, :bio, :todos]}

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :age, :integer
    field :email, :string
    field :bio, :string

    has_many :todos, PhoenixTodo.Todo

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name])
    |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

todo_model:

```
defmodule PhoenixTodo.Todo do
  use PhoenixTodo.Web, :model

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:title, :content]}

  schema "todos" do
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string

    belongs_to :user, PhoenixTodo.User

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [])
    |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

user_controller:

```
defmodule PhoenixTodo.UserController do
    use PhoenixTodo.Web, :controller

    alias PhoenixTodo.User

    def index(conn, _params) do
        json(conn, User |> Repo.all() |> Repo.preload(:todos))
    end

    def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
        json(conn, User|> Repo.get(id) |> Repo.preload(:todos))
    end

    def create(conn, data) do
      user = User.changeset(%User{}, data)
      #user = User.changeset(%User{}, %{name: "xxx", todos: [%PhoenixTodo.Todo{}]})
      json conn, user
    end
end
```

I can get all users or query particular user from `:index` and `:show`, but `:create` will always raise an error about `association`.

Request with: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name": "abc"}' http://localhost:4000/api/users`

Error raised like this: `cannot encode association :todos from PhoenixTodo.User to JSON because the association was not loaded. Please make sure you have preloaded the association or remove it from the data to be encoded`

How to preload `:todos` when `:create`? And `todos` is not a required field when creating user, can we ignore that association?

Comment: Did you forget to do `Repo.insert`? Creating a changeset will not insert the user in the database.

Comment: @Dogbert I think it's not caused by `Repo.insert`. But I add that before returning json, and the same error raised. And code of `:create` now looks like `user = User.changeset(%User{}, data)  Repo.insert(user)  json conn user`

Comment: Yes, as you figured out, you should pass the user struct returned by `Repo.insert` to `json`, not the changeset.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I make it works.

This turns out that `json conn user` matters. It seems like `json` will call `Poison` to encode the `Ecto.Changeset`, **not a `Ecto.Model`**, which return by `changeset`. So we should pass a `Ecto.Model` to json.

And here's how I do it.

```
user = User.changeset(%User{}, data)
IO.inspect user  # Ecto.Changeset
{:ok, u1} = Repo.insert(user)
IO.inspect u1   # Model!!
json conn, u1 |> Repo.preload(:todos)  # now we can successfully preload :todos
```